# Filtering tensors element in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

What's the equivalent operation in Tensorflow for this? For example, I have a `x = np.array([-12,4,6,8,100])`. I want to do as simple as this: `x = x[x>5]`, but I can't find any TF operation for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `TF` you can do something like this to achieve similar results.

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 

x = np.array([-12,4,6,8,100])
y = tf.gather(x, tf.where(x > 5))
y.numpy().reshape(-1)
array([  6,   8, 100])
```

**Details**

The [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where#retrieving_indices_of_true_elements) will return the **indices** of `condition` that are `True`. Such as

```
x = np.array([-12,4,6,8,100])
tf.where(x > 5)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]])>
```

And next, using [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather), it slices from params (`x`) axis according to **indices** (from `tf.where`). Such as

```
tf.gather(x, tf.where(x > 5))
```